# react router v6.3.0 http://localhost:3000/https://example.com/ issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Index.jsx** is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
 </React.StrictMode>,
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.jsx** is

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { lightTheme } from './components/Themes';
import { Route, Routes, useLocation } from 'react-router';
import { About } from './components/About';
import { Main } from './components/Main';
import { Blog } from './components/Blog';
import { Work } from './components/Work';
import { Skill } from './components/Skill';
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import { Music } from './components/partials/Music';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

   return (
<>
  <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
    <Music />
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
        <Route path="/work" element={<Work />} />
        <Route path="/skill" element={<Skill />} />
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  </ThemeProvider>
</>
  );
 }

export default App;
```

**SocialIcons.jsx** is

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { Facebook, Github, Twitter, YouTube } from '../AllSvgs';
import { DarkTheme } from '../Themes';

export const SocialIcons = (props) => {
  return (
<div className="socialIcon">
  <motion.div
    initial={{ transform: 'scale(0)' }}
    animate={{ scale: [0, 1, 1.5, 1] }}
    transition={{ type: 'spring', duration: 1, delay: 1 }}
  >
    <NavLink
      style={{ color: 'inherit' }}
      target="_blank"
      to={{ pathname: 'https://github.com/faha1999' }}
    >
      <Github
        width={25}
        height={25}
        fill={props.theme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme.text : DarkTheme.body}
      />
    </NavLink>
  </motion.div>

</div>
 );
};
```

When I click the GitHub icon React router redirects to the link like http://localhost:3000/https://github.com/ or http://example.com/https://github.com/ where usually the like is https://github.com/.

I have no idea why every time this link is generating like this.

**How to solve this issue?**

Comment: What is the issue? What are you asking for? Can you edit your post to include a code example producing an issue? See [mcve]. We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.

Comment: @DrewReese now check, please.

Comment: `react-router-dom` links only link to pages internal to the app. If you need to link to an external site use a regular anchor tag. `to={{ pathname: 'https://github.com/faha1999' }}` will simply append `"https://github.com/faha1999"` to the end of the current URL path.

Comment: I did the same thing as you said but the URL is generated like http://localhost:3000/https://github.com/faha1999 why this is happening? is there an error? why http://localhost:3000/ or http://example.com/ is added before   https://github.com/faha1999 @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direct  tag and redirect to the external site like below, hope this works for you. Normally redirecting to the external site we can use  tag, and it will work as expected.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { Facebook, Github, Twitter, YouTube } from '../AllSvgs';
import { DarkTheme } from '../Themes';

export const SocialIcons = (props) => {
  return (
<div className="socialIcon">
  <motion.div
    initial={{ transform: 'scale(0)' }}
    animate={{ scale: [0, 1, 1.5, 1] }}
    transition={{ type: 'spring', duration: 1, delay: 1 }}
  >
    <a
      style={{ color: 'inherit' }}
      target="_blank"
      href='https://github.com/faha1999'
    > {/* Here I change from NavLing to anchor tag.  */}
      <Github
        width={25}
        height={25}
        fill={props.theme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme.text : DarkTheme.body}
      />
    </a>
  </motion.div>

</div>
 );
};
```

Comment: Yes, the anchor tag works instead of NavLink. But my question is why NavLink does not work like the anchor tag?

Comment: @KawsarAhmedFahad Because RRD links only link to internal pages. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914500/react-router-v6-3-0-http-localhost3000-https-example-com-issue#comment128785791_72914500).

Comment: okay, thanks. I understand the issue.